# How to get the labels of a selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have wanted to see how could I return only the labels from these set of checkboxes when they selected. 
Here is the code:

```
<label class="threeLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkBusinessActivityStore" name= "Business" class="validate-reqchk-byname label: 'Business Activity'" > "&nbsp;&nbsp;Store"
</label>
<label class="threeLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkBusinessActivityCoffeeShop" name= "Business" class="validate-reqchk-byname label: 'Business Activity'" > "&nbsp;&nbsp;Coffee Shop"
</label>
<label class="threeLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkBusinessActivityBar" name= "Business" class="validate-reqchk-byname label: 'Business Activity'" > "&nbsp;&nbsp;Bar"
</label>
```

Comment: That is not valid HTML. Each one of those `label`s is missing a `>`

Comment: Thank you I just typed it wrong on here, but those fixes are applied to my project

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your html syntax (close elements, etc). Then you can add click event listeners to your inputs, check if they are "checked", and get the label text from the parent label. For example:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (const input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const elem = event.currentTarget;
    if (elem.checked) {
      const label = elem.parentNode.textContent;
      console.log(label);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<label class="threeLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBusinessActivityStore" name="Business" class="validate-reqchk-byname label: 'Business Activity'">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Store
</label>
<label class="threeLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBusinessActivityCoffeeShop" name="Business" class="validate-reqchk-byname label: 'Business Activity'">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Coffee Shop
</label>
<label class="threeLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBusinessActivityBar" name="Business" class="validate-reqchk-byname label: 'Business Activity'">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Bar
</label>
```

Comment: I have a click even already where they click the check boxes they update their application. I just want to retrieve the labels of the boxes because I want to pass them to another page.

Comment: @prch - you can get the labels from the click event using `event.target.parentNode` once your html syntax issues are corrected. Run the snippet above and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Okay let me give it a go